# How to use Xpath in PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: web-scraping

I am learning scraping using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and Xpath. Accroding to the changelog given here http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=218559. The PHP SImple HTML DOM Parser supports xpath generated from Firebug. But I am not able to figure out how to use it. Can anyone show me an example of the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find function.
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find

```
$content = file_get_html($link);

$elems = $content->find("/html/body/div/div");
```

Answer (score 1):

There's find function in Simple HTML DOM Parser. BUT it accepts selectors!
So you cant just write

```
$html = file_get_html($link);
$elements = $html->find("/html/body/div/p");
```

because then you'll get more than one element!

to get just exact element marked by XPath, write

```
$element = $html->find("/html/body/div[1]/p[1]", 0);
```