# Extract all div contents with "HTML tags" in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, web-scraping, web-crawler

I have to extract some content of some specific div having css class e.g "entire-content". But the important is to get the content with HTML tags.

```
$ch = curl_init("http://hihi2.com/2014/04/14/p215331.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', "UTF-8");
@$dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">'.$cl);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

$title = $xpath->query("//div[@class='float_right']/span/a");


echo "<pre>";
foreach ($title as $key=>$value){
   $titlear[$key] = ($value->nodeValue);
}
```

It gives me the whole contents as a text and I need text surrounded by it's tags.

Comment: @RahilWazir, It's there on the URL of his code..

Comment: http://hihi2.com/2014/04/14/p215331.html, this url is having the required div, which is having css class "entire-content"

Comment: @Ihsanullahkhan The provided link doesn't have any `entire-content` class

Comment: @RahilWazir sorry the class name is "entry-content".

Comment: This link should probably be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378107/how-to-use-xpath-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser The important thing is using xpath.