# php simple_html_dom scraping issue

Tags: php, xpath, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a content from one site using the simple_html_dom using this code

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.aswaqcity.com/thread1230092.html');
//echo $html;
// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]') as $article) {
    $item['title']      = $article->find('/div[1]/strong', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

I got the xpath from firebug options but there is nothing scraped.

Comment: @Enissay So, are the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378107/how-to-use-xpath-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser) wrong? Not familiar with PHP, just curious. It seems to me XPath expressions can be used: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Scratch that, both are supported (my bad)... I tried to explore the code, but it looks like it has some encoding problem when displaying the result and which I couldn't solve...

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to find on this page. What would be the expected output? @Enissay No worries - I misread specifications all the time myself..

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the `tbody` isn't really there. HTML browsers will add those to the dom whenever they are missing.

Also you should be using css instead of xpath, it's the whole point of using simple-html-dom.

Comment: Why is using CSS the point of simple-html-dom? (No criticism intended, I am asking out of curiosity)

Comment: Because you don't need simple-html-dom to get that stuff with xpath. There's built-in Dom functions that can do that.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks! Also, + 1 - `tbody` is the culprit most likely.